# How to test a mailer that has a date with accents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, testunit

In my mailer I have a date with Spanish format:

> sábado, 21 de julio del 2012

I have a custom formatter for that configured in my config/locales/es.yml

```
my_date_format: ! '%A, %-d de %B del %Y, %k:%M'
```

I'm trying to test it this way:

```
test "date with accent" do
  mail = MyMailer.my_template

  assert_match I18n.l(@object.date, format: :my_date_format), mail.body.encoded
end
```

But it fails:

> # Running tests:
>
> F
>
> Finished tests in 0.438078s, 2.2827 tests/s, 15.9789 assertions/s.
>
> 1) Failure: test_date_with_accent(MyMailerTest)
>   [test/unit/mailers/my_mailer_test.rb:12]: Expected /sábado,\ 21\ de\
>   julio\ del\ 2012,\ 14:10/ to match "...... .......s=C3=A1bado, 21 de
>   julio del 2012, 14:10\r\n ........".

(I have omitted the rest of the email content)

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue. As far as I know, mail.body.encoded will be of a binary encoding and the I18n string is a utf-8 encoded. Try this : `assert_match ......., mail.body.encoded.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")`

Comment: I get exactly the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the encoded body is "quoted printable", let's encode the testing date.

First we create a custom method for String:

```
class String
  def to_quoted_printable(*args)
    [self].pack("M").gsub(/\=\n/, "")
  end
end
```

This can be placed inside test_helper.rb

Next we just use that custom method to prepare the date value, so the match can be done:

```
assert_match I18n.l(@object.date, format: :my_date_format).to_quoted_printable, mail.body.encoded
```

Now the date is properly encoded and the test will pass.

**Or even simpler**, it's not necessary to encode the email body, so this can also be done:

```
assert_match I18n.l(@object.date, format: :my_date_format), mail.text_part.body.to_s
```